# Trying to detect if multiple files are present in multipart/form-data request, and rejecting multiple attachments

Tags: go, io, multipartform-data

I am building an API using Go that needs to store a file that is sent in a multipart form request. It also needs to return an error if more than one file is attached, and the files do not have key values attached. I'm running into an issue where the Part for the Multipart Reader changes upon iteration. So I can either successfully upload the first file but not return the error, or it returns an error when needed, but when a valid request comes in - it iterates past it and uploads nothing.

I have written a couple `for` loops trying this, and some without.

```golang
i := 0
var data io.Reader
for part, err := reader.NextPart(); err != io.EOF; part, err := reader.NextPart() {
    i++
    data = part
}
if i > 1 {
    return nil, errors.New("too many files")
}

req := storeRequest{
   Data:      data,
   FileNAme:  r.URL.Path,
}

return req, nil
```

Any suggestions on how I could handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and files do not have key values attached" -- could you clarify this part? Or is it not that relevant to the question/code at hand?